# Getting following complie error

Tags: spring

I get this compile time error. Not sure what as gone wrong in it. It says that the qualifier annotation is not allowed above the setter method

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Qualifier` is only allowed on fields and attributes not methods. 
You can also use it on the methods argument

See the docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html

```
    @Autowired
    public void prepare(@Qualifier("main") MovieCatalog movieCatalog, CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
    this.movieCatalog = movieCatalog;
    this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
}
```